# In SoapUI is there a way to override the default behavior of the WSDL required fields for a single test case? 

Tags: xml, soapui

I have a TestCase that the API states that to Update the UserType I need to pass in the following XML. So I change the XML in the XML tab and run the test and it will do the update.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:mup="http://www.XXX.com/it/enterprise/emc/v1/mup" 
xmlns:mup1="http://www.XXX.com/it/enterprise/emc/v1/muptypes">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
  <mup:UpSertUserProfileRequest>
     <mup:userProfileInfo>
        <mup1:userUid>${Properties#userUid}</mup1:userUid>
        <mup1:userType>Lite User</mup1:userType>
        <mup1:changeMode>AdminProfileUpdate</mup1:changeMode>
     </mup:userProfileInfo>
  </mup:UpSertUserProfileRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

When I run the test a second time the The testCase response is "failure". When I look at the XML includes other fields required in the schema.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:mup="http://www.XXX.com/it/enterprise/emc/v1/mup"
xmlns:mup1="http://www.XXX.com/it/enterprise/emc/v1/muptypes">
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
   <mup:UpSertUserProfileRequest>
     <mup:userProfileInfo>
        <mup1:userUid>${Properties#userUid}</mup1:userUid>
       <mup1:loginName/><mup1:businessEmailAddress/><mup1:password/><mup1:firstName/><mup1:lastName/><mup1:primaryPhoneNumber/><mup1:alternatePhoneNumber/><mup1:alternateEmailAddress/><mup1:userStatus/><mup1:userType>Lite User</mup1:userType>
       <mup1:partyId/><mup1:entityId/><mup1:siteDunsNo/><mup1:globalDunsNo/><mup1:domesticDunsNo/><mup1:parentDunsNo/><mup1:osr/><mup1:siteAddress1/><mup1:siteAddress2/><mup1:city/><mup1:state/><mup1:country/><mup1:zipCode/><mup1:siteName/><mup1:screenName/><mup1:userLocation/><mup1:secretQuestionOneId/><mup1:secretQuestionOneValue/><mup1:secretQuestionTwoValue/><mup1:secretQuestionTwoId/><mup1:changeMode>AdminProfileUpdate</mup1:changeMode><mup1:changeType/><mup1:preferredAddress1/><mup1:preferredAddress2/><mup1:preferredCity/><mup1:preferredState/><mup1:preferredCountry/><mup1:preferredZipCode/><mup1:overrideEmailCheck/><mup1:registrationFromDate/><mup1:registrationToDate/><mup1:userValidated/><mup1:companyProfileId/><mup1:docsPerPage/><mup1:userCreatedDate/><mup1:lastActivityDate/><mup1:sortBy/><mup1:sortOrder/><mup1:pageNumber/><mup1:resultsPerPage/><mup1:searchIdentityStr/><mup1:searchAttrName/><mup1:searchAttrValue/><mup1:searchCompProfName/><mup1:partyNumber/><mup1:termsCheck/><mup1:regCompleteCheck/><mup1:demoteCheck/><mup1:srchPrefLang/><mup1:userLockStatus/><mup1:primPhAreaCd/><mup1:primPhCountryCd/><mup1:prefPhAreaCd/><mup1:prefPhCountryCd/><mup1:adminUserName/><mup1:regValCode/><mup1:ngadmUserLock/><mup1:siteSpecOSR/>
     </mup:userProfileInfo>
  </mup:UpSertUserProfileRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

So I am asking: In SoapUI is there a way to override the default behavior of the WSDL required fields for a single test case?

Answer (score 0):

When you leave the form view SoapUI automatically enforces the required fields from the WSDL to the XML and this behavior cannot be over written. I changed a setting in my preferences/soapUI Pro / Default Request editor: to source, and avoid the form view when in this test case.
In short, This is a known issue with SoapUI. It is listed for change in a future upgrade of SoapUI.